# How style-loader works with css-loader?

Tags: webpack

I know that style-loader adds CSS to a dom by injecting a  tag. And css-loader gets css as string when it meets `require('./style.css');`.

But, How style-loader plays with css-loader??

I'm reading style-loader source code and css-loader source code. But I cannot understand how they play together.

How the css string which css-loader gets from style.css is passed to style-loader?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question. I've done quite some homework in order to properly answer it. Here's what I found.

#### Normal Loader

The common understanding of webpack loaders, is that they are units chained-up to form a pipeline. Each loader processes the input source code, transforms it, then passes the result down to the next unit in the pipeline. And this process repeats until the last unit done its job.

But above is only part of the whole picture, only true for *normal loaders*. `style-loader` is not a normal loader, because it also has a *pitch* method.

---

#### The `pitch` Method of Loader

Note, there's no such thing as *pitch loader*, cus every loader can have a "normal side" and "pitch side".

Here's the not-very-helpful [webpack doc on pitching loader](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#pitching-loader). The most useful info is the concept of "pitch phase" and "normal phase" and their execution order.

```
|- a-loader `pitch`
  |- b-loader `pitch`
    |- c-loader `pitch`
      |- requested module is picked up as a dependency
    |- c-loader normal execution
  |- b-loader normal execution
|- a-loader normal execution
```

You've seen `style-loader`'s [source code](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/blob/master/src/index.js#L10), the export looks like:

```
module.exports = {}
module.exports.pitch = function loader(request) {
  /* ... */
  return [/* some string */].join('\n')
}
```

The only related part in the doc to above source code:

> if a loader delivers a result in the pitch method the process turns around and skips the remaining loaders.

It's still quite unclear on how exactly this pitch thing works.

#### Digging Deeper

I finally came across this [blog post](https://juejin.im/post/5bc1a73df265da0a8d36b74f) (written in chinese tho) talks about the detail. Specifically, it analyses the exact case like in `style-loader` where the `pitch` method returns something.

As per the blog, the `pitch` method is mainly used to access and modify metadata early in the loader process. Returning from `pitch` method is indeed rare, and poorly documented. But when it does return sth other than `undefined`, here's what happens:

```
# Normal execution order is disrupted.
|- style-loader `pitch` # <-- because this guy returns string early
# below steps are all canceled out
  |- css-loader `pitch`
    |- requested module is picked up as a dependency
  |- css-loader normal execution
|- style-loader normal execution
```

Then the return value from `styleLoader.pitch` just **becomes a new in-memory file entry**. This file is then loaded like a normal file and transformed using a brand new load process.

If you check, the content of this on-the-fly generated file from `styleLoader.pitch` looks something like

```
var content = require("!!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-3!./index.css");
```

You'll notice every `require` request is fully configured using inline query. Thus these request won't go through any `test` in `webpackConfig.module.rules`.

#### Conclusion

Basically, this is what `style-loader` does:

1. it captures a request early by exposing a `pitch` method.
2. it then understands what this request is about, read the config of all following-up loaders, transforms all config to inline-queried `require(...)`
3. it then issues a new file on-the-fly, and by doing this, the original request is effectively *canceled then replaced* by a new request to this in-memory file.

I don't know any better, all truth is held in the [source code](https://github.com/webpack/loader-runner/blob/master/lib/LoaderRunner.js) of `loader-runner` module. If anyone has better ref sources or understanding, please comment, post an answer or edit mine.